# How to get source code of .NET libraries to VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was told that Microsoft has released reference source code for some .NET libraries (I'm especially interested in C# libraries). If it is true, I would like to download that code and use it with my VS, so I can browse the code by selecting

> Go to Declaration

and

> Go to Implementation

from context menu. It would be much better then just to see documentation in object browser.
So how do I get VS to work with it? Thank you.

Comment: You can download the source code for the .NET Framework so that you can step into functions, but you still won't be able to use features like "Go to Definition".

Comment: But then the code must be fyzically present on my computer, can I browse it any other way then by clicking "Go to definition" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) is reference source code for.NET from Microsoft that available for download.

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx) is how to set up VS for debuging.

Comment: these no longer exist

Answer (score 10):

**Up-to-Date answer**

All you need is this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 7):

Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) and you may also checkout the [following article](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx) and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) also. This allows you to step through the framework source code while debugging your applications. [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is also a good tool for browsing through the compiled assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Darin said nearly everything. The only hint that is missing is the [NetMassDownloader](http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/) to get the whole source once if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The .net core, .net 5 and .net 6 runtime code can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

> This repo contains the code to build the .NET runtime, libraries and shared host (dotnet) installers for all supported platforms, as well as the sources to .NET runtime and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

here you go: [.net source code download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D)

good luck in compiling it so you can debug through it like it was one of your own projects.  I don't know how big a project you've ever worked on, but this one's a big one and its not as simple as you would imagine...

Comment: After downloading it and having had a look at it, I did imagine it as more difficult. However, you're right on the first one, it's still ridiculously complicated and time-consuming to get a larger project with a few dependencies to compile under windows.

Comment: @Quandary: I've never really had a problem getting even the most complex project with lots of dependencies to compile under Windows. Not knowing how to use the tools properly doesn't mean that Windows sucks. If you really don't like .NET and the rest of the Microsoft stack as much as it seems, why do you insist on participating in discussions on those tools?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I know very well how to use these tools. And their pitfalls as well. It's just that downloading and installing libaries MANUALLY takes very long, which wastes my time. However, they  finally are addressing this problem now, with nuGet, but never mind C++ or C - or the fact that the nuGet installer is broken. And BTW, just having a different opinion of Microsoft than you doesn't mean I'm not allowed to participate in discussions on their tools - well, not as long as MS doesn't run this site anyway. And yea, I think Windows (Vista+) sucks, but not the rest of the MS stack.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said about the Reference Source site as well as sources on GitHub. Visual Studio has a feature called [Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink). This allows Nuget packages (DotNet Frameworks included) to include the original source code in the package so that you can navigate to the source for can code that you may be calling from directly within Visual Studio just as if it was your own code. This also allows you to set breakpoints in that code.

If a package doesn't include the original source code, you should still be able right click on any class or method and select "Go To Definition"(F12) and [Visual Studio will attempt to decompile to code for you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/decompilation-of-c-code-made-easy-with-visual-studio/).